# When we throw a ball at an angle, shouldn't it go the way it came because of equal and opposite reaction?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

If I throw a ball and it strikes at an angle $x$ , shouldn't it go back the same way? I was wondering about this in my Physics class and couldn't find a similar question.

Comment: Do you mean *come back* the same way?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the force which the surface exerts on the ball is in the opposite direction to the one in which the ball is moving. Is this realistic?

Comment: yup. I meant come back the same way

Comment: @PhilipWood The direction of the force exerted by ball on wall is the same as the direction of the motion of the ball isn't it?

Comment: It's usually at right angles to the surface,

Comment: Yeah you are right, I was thinking that when i was writing, but wrote sth else

Comment: Energy loss is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR only part of the ball gets an opposite reaction.**

When two objects meet such that the relative direction of collision is at an angle to the surface of contact, they *do* in fact interact in an "equal and opposite" fashion. But because they only collide at one point on the surface (realistically, one small area due to the elasticity of the material) and that point is not the center of mass, the equal and opposite forces cause both objects to torque as they deflect. This does change the overall linear momentum in the parallel-to-surface direction by converting it to angular momentum.

Answer (score 0):

If and only if the balls strikes the surface at a perpendicular angle and the collision is entirely elastic and you ignore air resistance. If it is now perpendicular then it will go off in a different direction, if it's not elastic it won't quite come back along the same path and the same goes for ignoring air resistance.

Comment: That's what I wanted to ask. Even if it strikes at an angle WHY doesn't it go back the way it came. Intuitively I know that it goes of in a different direction, but, according to the 3rd law of equal and opposite reaction, shouldn't  it go back the same path it came?  Correct me if I am wrong: The ball exerts a force on the wall in the direction of its motion.

Answer (score 0):

That would only happen if the ball strikes the wall at $90^o$, or at the maximum height of the ball's trajectory, should a wall not be present.  However, we here consider air resistance, and energy loss due to collision to be negligible, and the collision to be an elastic one.